# put data on textbox dynamically not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to enter the data to the previous page using ng-model. I moved to the next page after filling some data in textbox,after come to same page i want my data to be entered same as i entered previously, i write the code but its not working please tell me what i am doing wrong and thanks in advance

js code:-

```
$scope.notesPage = function() {
        $rootScope.data = {
            Name:               $scope.prospectName,
        };
        $location.path('/prospectNotes');
    };

    $scope.addProspect = function() {
        $rootScope.data.ProspectNotes = $scope.notes;
        $scope.ProspectNotes = "";
    };

    function fillFormData() {
        $scope.prospectName = $rootScope.data.Name;
    }

    $scope.addProspectForm = function() {
        $location.path('/create');
        fillFormData();

    }

    first html page

    <div class = "container" id = "form-container">
            <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "prospectName"> Prospect Name:
                    <img src = "images/required.gif" alt = "Required" class = "required-star">
                </label>

                <input type = "text" id = "prospectName" name = "prospectName" ng-model = "prospectName"
                       class = "form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class = "form-group">

                <button type="submit" class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary" ng-click="notesPage()"
                        style="margin-left:10px;"> Next </button>
            </div>
    </div>

     second html page

     <div class = "container" id = "form-container">

             <div class = "form-group">
                 <label for = "notes"> Notes for Prospect {{data.Name}}</label>
                 <textarea rows="20" id = "notes" name = "notes" ng-model = "notes" class = "form-control"></textarea>
             </div>

             <div class = "form-group">
                 <input type="button" id="cancel-button" value="Back" class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary"
                        ng-click="addProspectForm()">
                 <button type="submit" class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary" ng-click="addProspect()"
                         style="margin-left:10px;"> Add </button>
             </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Are you used $routeProvider for routing?

Comment: no i am not using  $routeProvider

Comment: $location.path('/prospectNotes'); while performing this where it will look for the page? Can you post your app.js..

Comment: .when('/prospectNotes', {
                templateUrl: 'views/addProspectNote.html',
                controller: 'AddProspectCtrl',
                title: 'Prospect Note'
            })

Comment: For both page Are you using same controller? If yes means, check whether $rootscope having value or not.

Comment: yes  $rootscope having value  but it not showing please tell what i am doing wrong

Comment: I need a full app.js then only i can find the problem.